# 404 returned on any URL accessed before accessing the home URL

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am using react-router for my app, when I deployed it on the server I noticed that if I requested any URL before opening the home URL, it will return 404. Then after accessing the home URL, all other URLs will work fine!

**index.tsx:**

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>
  ,
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);
```

**App.tsx:**

```
public render()
  {
    return(
        <div className="App">
            <div className="row margin-auto">
                <Header/>
                <Main/>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
  }
```

**Main.tsx:**

```
public render()
    {
        return (
            <div id="main" className="col col-9-and-half no-padding-h vh-100">
                <div className="container-fluid no-padding-h">
                    <main>
                        <Switch>
                            <Route path='/home' component={Home} />
                            <Route exact={true} path='/' component={Home} />
                            <Route path="/matches" component={Matches} />
                            <Route path='/login' component={Login} />
                            <Route path='/sign-up' component={SignUp} />
                            <Route path='/contact-us' component={ContactUs} />
                        </Switch>
                    </main>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

for example, when I try to open www.mywebsite.com/sign-up it will return 404, but if I opened www.mywebsite.com first then tried to access www.mywebsite.com/sign-up it will work fine.

Comment: Could you share what you are using to serve static files, and what your index.html looks like?

When using react router, you should redirect 404's to your index.html so react can initialize and let react-router handle rendering the proper route from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you [Seth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1842294/seth) & [William Chou](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7621726/william-chou) for guiding me to the answer, I made the following htaccess configs to handle the requests, and everything seems to work fine now:

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteBase /

    RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</ifModule>
```

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you don't have a redirect setup within your server. For a single page JavaScript application to work you must ensure that your server is serving your `index.html` for all paths.

One thing to note is that you will have to manage 404 handling within `react-router`. This can be achieved by adding a `<Route />` without a `path` prop to the end of your route definitions. It's important that it's at the end so that all route possibilities are exhausted before displaying a 404

```
<Switch>
  <Route path='/home' component={Home} />
  <Route exact={true} path='/' component={Home} />
  <Route path="/matches" component={Matches} />
  <Route path='/login' component={Login} />
  <Route path='/sign-up' component={SignUp} />
  <Route path='/contact-us' component={ContactUs} />
  <Route component={NotFound} />
</Switch>
```