# Using react-router-dom with Spring Boot

Tags: spring, reactjs

I encountered a problem and couldn't solve it anywhere.

I need to configure spring boot URL mapping so that all URLs (http://localhost:xxx/*) is mapped to my index.html, with all the URL parameters included.

As you know react-router-dom changes the URL dynamically. But when you refresh it, the URL will not be found.

Thank you.

Comment: are you doing server side rendering or using something like tomcat to serve your server and client?

Comment: I'm using tomcat to serve the api, and the index.html containing react.

Comment: When you're viewing the "/" and change the URL to "/about" using react-router-dom, then hit refresh, the server is trying to find the "/about" URL that does not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are using client side routing. When you go to /about, the server is looking for a static page in /about and can't find it. You need to config your tomcat war to point 404s to index.html and let react router handle router from there.

See this post:

[404 returned on any URL accessed before accessing the home URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53018322/404-returned-on-any-url-accessed-before-accessing-the-home-url#comment92939933_53018322)